# Compress and combine css and js files on deploy

Tags: git, model-view-controller, deployment, compression, capistrano

Every controller and action on site has own scripts(css and js). Is it possible to make snapshots of custom scripts for every controller after deploy ?

Example:

`example.com/users/list` using 2 js and 1 css

`example.com/project/list` using 5 js and 2 css

After deploying, it should be 4 custom snapshots (2 per request)

What I'am using : **Kohana, Capistrano, Git**

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. In addition, please post **relevant** error messages verbatim, and take the time to share the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Comment: There is no code on this moment. I need concept.